# Run macro to display error message when cell value exceeds 50

Tags: excel-2007

I've been up all night trying to figure this one out. I have a value derived from a formula in cell I6. This value represents the number of buy orders for a particular stock. I designed the spreadsheet so it only display 50 lines for buys and 50 lines for sells. When the value I6 exceeds 50, I want to display a message saying that "The number of buys )or sells) cannot exceed 50." I would like for this macro to run automatically anytime the value exceeds 50.

I should point out that I've never written a VB macro before, but I'm essentially fearless (as well as clueless).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this depending on how exactly you want to "Display a Message".

1. You could put a formulae in cell that checks the value of cell I6 something like:

   =IF(I6 > 50, "The number of buys / sells cannot exceed 50", "")

for this you would need an area where the message can display - you can even put some conditional formatting on the cell to display red if it contains any text.

1. Similar to the above, but doesn't rely on an area on your spread sheet and uses a VBA Macro.

a) Put the below forumlae in a cell (anywhere will do) not visible

```
=IF(I6 > 50, ToManyBuySells(),"")
```

b) add a module to the VBA project and add the following code.

```
Function ToManyBuySells()
    MsgBox "The number of (buys) or (sells) cannot exceed 50", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Buy/Sell Exceeded"
    ToManyBuySells = ""
End Function
```

This function will run when I6 goes over 50 and display the message.

Hope this helps